# How do I get USB or Ethernet working from an Apple Thunderbolt Display connected to PC with Thunderbolt support?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, drivers, thunderbolt

I have a newly built PC (winter 2014) that should be fully supported for Thunderbolt 2 with an [Asus Sabertooth Z97 Mark 1](http://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/SABERTOOTH_Z97_MARK_1/) motherboard and an accompanying [ThunderboltEX II](http://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ThunderboltEX_II/) PCIe card. Running Windows 8.1. I have my Apple Thunderbolt Display connected via Thunderbolt cable to the ThunderboltEX II card. The display and audio work great, looks beautiful.

Only (big) problem is I can not get the PC to recognize either the Ethernet or USB from the display. I haven't tested getting the display microphone to work yet. I'm wondering if there are drivers that need to be installed for Windows to make this work. I can not find anything in the manual for the motherboard.

My background: Mac OS X and Linux/Unix pro, Windows noob.

Comment: Does Windows Device Manager show any unknown devices?

Comment: Not that I can tell. It doesn't look like any of the USB ports are receiving power when the monitor is hooked up to the PC, either.

Comment: Also under devices, Windows shows the Apple Thunderbolt Display as just a "Generic PnP Monitor". I don't see any devices for Ethernet or USB that aren't from the motherboard, either.

Comment: It'll be a drivers problem. Generic monitor is a base class just to get it working. Any additional functionality will need drivers. Go to the display manufacturer's website and see if you can get them.

Comment: Did you ever get this working as also in the same boat ?

Comment: Nope. Also, one dumb thing I tried which **didn't work** was installing Apple's Bootcamp drivers. Another thing I noticed is that when the display was hooked up to the Mac, if I set the display volume to less than 100%, that would be the baseline for the PC volume. If you have super quiet audio from the display on the PC, check that.